# nivo slider not working properly

Tags: 7, javascript

I am new user of Drupal 7.3 also using [View Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) in our project but nivo slider not working properly.

When I am traying to uploading images in nivo slider, uploading time is too much. I think images is not uploading. Please give me solution and in status report I am getting error message i.e.

> "Error    Nivo Slider jQuery version  jQuery 1.4.4 .Nivo Slider requires
>   jQuery 1.7 or greater. Configure jQuery Update."

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that you need to download and install [Jquery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

Then you need to configure jquery update in

> /admin/config/development/jquery_update

and change the default version to grater than 1.7

Comment: no its not working.i installing this module and change version but its not working.in the status report the same error message will be occurd

Comment: @sachinGaikwad `clear cache` and check again because the error message clearly says it's jquery version issue. and do check your `Nivo slider` library version. also don't forget to read `README.txt` it contains all the documentations you need to follow to make it work. cheers.